# MFC Dialog Setting in DropDown Groups in a CDockablePane

Tags: c++, mfc, dialog

I want to host dialog items such as Sliders, buttons and Editboxes inside a CDockablePane. I want to have them in groups and each has separate dropdowns as shown in the picture below.
Is there some class in MFC to implement it?

[image]

Comment: [CMFCPropertyGridCtrl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cmfcpropertygridctrl-class).

Answer (score 0):

CMFCTasksPane is the class that provides this feature. Using addgroup will let you host different dialog classes as collapsable/expandable groups in it.